# Is it okay to say "I want to achieve something I dream of." without a "that" or similar right after "something"?

Tags: grammar

**Question.** I used to be told that a subordinate clause must be led by "that", "which" or similar connective, but I have constantly heard people saying the secondary clause without such connective, even by President Obama in a speech to school as I remember. So back to the title question, is it legitimate to not use such connective?

---

**Comment.** Some useful site for associated grammar would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It simply is not true that connectives such as “that” are always required in English. Ellipsis, the dropping of certain words that a native speaker will understand  as intended even though absent, is a feature of English. It is particularly common in American speech and informal writing. You must learn to expect it.

**HOWEVER**, your teachers are correct to warn you against using ellipsis yourself. When it is permitted is subtle; I doubt I could give you definitive guidance, and I tend to avoid it in formal writing. If you use ellipsis where a native speaker would not, your English will sound quite non-idiomatic, perhaps to the point that you are incomprehensible.

Here is the saving grace: ellipsis is never required. In some circumstances it is permitted, but you never need to use it. What your teachers are telling you is that avoiding ellipsis prevents ugly mistakes.